# how to modify a mediawiki main page so it looks like wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki

What do i need to do to make my newly installed wiki site looks like Wikipedia?
More specifically, I want to add different sections to the main page, such as, From today's featured article, Today's featured picture, etc. 
I have no idea where to begin with, please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they are just using tables, tables inside tables, and various styles in combination. Nothing really fancy.

You can view the source for any page on Wikipedia, including the front page. [Try it and see](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=edit), then you can copy it to your own wiki and start editing it to be more like what you prefer.

Comment: Of course, their layout is pretty sloppy and could stand to be cleaned up before you implement it, but just copying everything over directly should work fine. That's what I did when I created my first wiki.